# For an endomorphism $f:V\rightarrow V$, can we assure that it's also an automorphism?

Tags: linear-transformations

The only detail I know is that $f^2+2f+I=0$, with $I$ being the identity matrix and 0 being the trivial transformation (takes every vector to zero). Also, we're talking about linear transformations and $V$ is finite-dimensional. I don't know how to approach this problem, but my guess is this:

- The expression contains an $f^2$, so the matrix $A$ associated with $f$ must be a squared matrix.

So that points in the direction of $f$ being an automorphism, because squared, regular matrices are all associated with a particular, bijective linear transformation. But I have no idea how to find out if the associated matrix is regular, so I can just stop now and conclude that there's no way for me to assure that $f$ is an automorphism. Is there a way to go the extra step and find a definitive answer?

Comment: Do you know if $V$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: Yes, it is. I forgot to add it in the main post, I'll do it now.

Comment: Since $f$ is an endomorphism of a vector space, its matrix is square. Nothing useful will come out of the observation that it is square...

Comment: That's true, sorry. So I guess the key observation is what @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez poster in the first answer.

Comment: By the way, you can never conclude that you can «stop and conclude that there is no way to assure something» simply because you have no idea about how to do something. You cannot conclude something from ignorance.

Comment: I know, and you're right. I'm not speaking my native language and I didn't convey exactly what I meant. I edited it and added that there's no way for me to conclude anything with my current knowledge. Thanks for your criticism.

Answer (score 5):

From the equation it follows that $f(-f-2I)=I$ and $(-f-2I)f=I$ so that $-f-2I$ is an inverse for $f$ (and this works independently of whether $V$ is finite dimensional or not)

Comment: Oh, that's true, I hadn't thought of that! Thank you!